# VBScript FolderExist Object Doesn't support this Property

Tags: vbscript

I'm writing a vbScript and trying to verify a folder exists before creating it. I've googled and found some code on MSDN that is supposed to work, but it's failing with the error Object Doesn't support this property on the oFSO.FolderExists statement. See code below.

```
dirNameFE = InputBox("Enter the name of the Directory for the Front end Logs:","Front End Directory"  ,"C:\LogFiles\FrontEnd")

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not oFSO.FolderExist(dirNameFE) then
    set objFolder = oFSO.CreateFolder(dirNameFE)
End If
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: that's because it is FolderExists <---- notice the s at the end

Comment: Thank you. can't believe I missed that.